# CanIi change ubuntu remote desktop port to something else

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I am using Ubuntu on my server.

i am behind router.

There is another server in my company where someone has forwarded the port 5900 to.

Can I change something in my Ubuntu so that I can connect using VNC on port 5905

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Set as default option was overlooked.
This process allegedly fixes the issue of the port change not taking even after a reboot.

1. Open Gnome Configuration Editor - gconf-editor (can use ALT-F2 for quick access)
2. Open Folder Desktop
3. Open Folder Gnome
4. Open Folder remote_access
5. In right had pane:
6. Right Click on alternative_port and click on edit key
7. Enter desired port number
8. Click OK
9. Again Right Click on alternative_port and click on Set as Default (this is important)

   10. Enter the Admin password for Authentication and click on Authenticate
   11. Right click on authentication_methods and edit key – and set to vnc
   12. Put a check in the check box for enabled
   13. Put a check in the check box for use_alternative_port
   14. Click on File and Close Window
   15. Reboot the system

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1297290

Comment: I have entered 5905 as port number and made true the use alternative port but still i can't connect using ip:5905. i have restarted the system as well. ip:5900 works

Comment: In the authentication_methods , i have no option set , it says none. and after doing all other setting , i still can't access that

Comment: And it still works on 5900? Are u going through the firewall? Im thinking its got to be something simple

Comment: yes , it works on 5900 , i don't have any firewall

Comment: I will try to reproduce the problem on a server at work tomorrow :)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this Master?? Just curious